# BLE: Reconnect Android central to iOS peripheral

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-ble

After days of research and trial and error my colleagues and I have to hope that the StackOverflow community has a working solution.

We got an Android Smartwatch. We developed an app which acts as the BLE central. The App shows a QR-Code encoding an UUID which is unique for every Smartwatch. While showing that QR code it's actively scanning for a device advertising a service with that UUID.

We also developed an iOS app which can scan that QR code and start advertising with the service UUID it received. The Android Smartwatch then connects very quickly to the iOS device.

One purpose of the Smartwatch is to show push notifications from the iOS device. So when the connection is successfully established, the Smartwatch-App subscribes to the ANCS Data Source and Notification Source characteristics. This initiates "Just Works" pairing, so you just have to click on "Pair" on the iOS device. Afterwards you have to allow that iOS notifications are shared to the Smartwatch and then the Smartwatch successfully receives notifications.
ANCS is also the reason why the iOS device MUST BE in the peripheral role.

Until here everything works fine.

When the user leaves the bluetooth range or dis- and enables bluetooth on the iOS device, an automatic reconnect should be triggered. It DOES reconnect when the iOS app is in foreground. Unfortunately it DOES NOT work when the iOS-App is in background. This is probably related to the fact, that the iOS device is not advertising with the required UUID when the app is in background as described in the CoreBluetooth documentation:

```
All service UUIDs contained in the value of the CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey advertisement key are placed in a special “overflow” area; they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them.
```

We tried many different ways to reconnect from the Android Smartwatch to iOS. From my understanding it should be working when making the first connectGatt with autoConnect=false and when the connection is lost, calling connectGatt on the lost device with autoConnect=true, but it never reconnects. At least not within 15 minutes. Scanning again also wouldn't work, as the UUID is not advertised in background anymore.

We also tried to additionally let the Android device act as peripheral, so the iOS can connect to it. After connecting we wrote data to an "INITIATE_ANCS"-characteristic and let the Android device call connectGatt on the device which was passed to onCharacteristicWrite. This led to interesting behavior:
- The connection was working, we could read a Smartwatch-Characteristic from iOS.
- When subscribing to the ANCS characteristics, it initiated pairing. But instead of "Just Works" pairing it showed a 6-digit code on the iOS device which we had to type onto the Smartwatch.
- The pairing was inititated on every new connect and it always created a new device in the systems device managers on both Android and iOS.
- The pairing WAS NOT inititated when the iOS app was in background.

We really did a thorough research and couldn't find a solution. Did we understand something wrong on how BLE for iOS and Android works? We really hope to find an expert here that has the knowledge what has to be done to make the reconnect work.

Edit:
The Android device is running on Android 5.1.1 and currently it's no option to update.
The iOS testing device is running iOS 13.3 and it should be compatible with iOS 13+

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am trying to get an Android device to detect an iOS peripheral, when the iOS app is in the background. The Android device has to be able to detect based on a service UUID, and detect even if it has not connected or paired with the iOS device before.

Comment: Unfortunately not. My "solution" is to have the watch running in peripheral and central mode. The iOS device runs in central mode when there is no connection. The iOS device can search in background and when the watch is found a push notification is shown. When clicking the notification on the iOS device the app is opened, enters peripheral mode and then the watch can connect to it. While the connection is established the watch is running only as central and the iOS device only as peripheral.

Comment: Ahimsa Das suggested that android can can still connect with an iOS device (iOS app in background mode), by doing the following : first identify Apple device by manufacturer code, connect, then...check available services (see if there is a service matching your app), would you be able to try it? I’m coding in iOS and it would take a while for me to test with android...

Comment: @KaizerSozay, how would you identify Apple device by the manufacturer code? When I try to `getManufacturerSpecificData()` from the `ScanResult` I get a byte array with the length 10 where only the first byte is set to 6 and all the others are 0s.